# Como obtener info externa usando GAM External Authentication en Genexus SD

Tags: genexus

GX16

Generador c#

estoy armando un sistema WEB/SD que usa [GAM External Authentication: version 2.0](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?21555,GAM%20External%20Authentication%3A%20version%202.0,#3%20User%20roles%20passed%20to%20the%20application%20that%20uses%20GAM) en GX16. El escenario es que tengo n sistemas externos cada uno con sus usuarios y claves. Tengo que armar un  nuevo manteniendo usuarios y claves de cada uno de los sistemas ya en uso.

Hice funcionar el login externo mediante webservices y ambiente WEB sin problemas,  con el ejemplo que trae el GAM en GAMExampleLogin y pude obtener `&GAMExampleSDTApplicationData` con datos del sistema externo en el nuevo sistema.

Ahora quiero hacer lo mismo en pero en ambiente SD, vi que es diferente lo que trae el GAM de fábrica en el GAMSDLogin pero pude loguearme con el sistema externo.

Lo que no pude es obtener los datos del sistema externo, hago esto:

```
GeneXus.SD.Actions.LoginExternal(GAMAuthenticationTypes.ExternalWebService, &User, &Password, &LoginExternalAdditionalParameters)
&GAMSession=GamSession.Get(&GAMError) //ACA SE CAE LA APP SD
&ApplicationData = &GamSession.GetApplicationData() //ACA NO LLEGA NUNCA
```

Entonces no puedo obtener los datos asociados al usuario externo.

¿Alguna ayuda de que puede estar pasando? ¿Quizá no estoy haciendo la forma correcta en SD para obtener los datos asociados al usuario logueado en SD? ¿Porqué CRASHEA la app SD un vez que te logueaste cuando pedís el objeto GamSession? ¿Será que está mal la forma de pedirlo?

Muchas gracias

Bruno

Answer (score 0):

Me contesto yo mismo y les cuento como solucioné por si a alguien le sirve:

cree un proc "ExtraDatosSesion"y lo hice webservice y retorna `&GAMExampleSDTApplicationData`:

```
 &ApplicationData = GAMSession.GetApplicationData()
 &GAMExampleSDTApplicationData.FromJson(&ApplicationData)
```

Luego de loguearme en la app SD con LoginExternal llamo a ese proc y listo.
Tengo los datos `&GAMExampleSDTApplicationData` en el sd

Saludos,
Bruno

Encontré este [doc](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?37703,HowTo%3A%20Get%20user%27s%20additional%20information%20from%20the%20GAM%20Identity%20Provider,) de la wiki que tiene una forma mas elegante de hacerlo también